# Firestore security rules document id causing Null value error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am working on securing my Firestore database and am having trouble with a collection wildcard. I have a root-level collection called `study`, I want to allow reads only if the `status` field is set to "published".

My current security rules are as follows

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   
  ...

  function isStudyPublished(studyId) {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/study/$(studyId)).data.status == "published";
  }

  ...

  // Match for participant permissioning
  match /study/{studyId}/{document=**} {
    // Deny all requests to create, update, or delete the study
    allow create, update, delete: if false

    // Allow the requestor to read the study if it is published
    allow read: if isStudyPublished(studyId)
  }

  ...

  }
}
```

This security rule works great when requesting a single document, but not when doing a collection-level query. I get the error message: `Null value error. for 'list'`. I understand that Firestore rules do not act as a filter, however, I believe my query should only be requesting documents where the `status` field equals "published".

Here are my two queries:

```
// successfully retrieves a single document
export const getStudy: GetStudy = (studyId) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getDoc(doc(firestore, COLLECTION_KEYS.STUDY, studyId))
      .then((doc) => {
        resolve(dataToStudy(doc.id, doc.data()));
      })
      .catch((error) => reject(error));
  });
};
```

```
// fails to retrieve multiple documents
export const getStudies: GetStudies = (cursor) => {
  const studies: StudyDoc[] = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let q = query(collection(firestore, COLLECTION_KEYS.STUDY), where("status", "==", "published"), orderBy(FIELD_KEYS.UPDATED));

    if (cursor) q = query(q, startAfter(cursor));

    getDocs(q)
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          studies.push(dataToStudy(doc.id, doc.data()));
        });

        return resolve([studies, snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1]]);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return reject(error);
      });
  });
};
```

My initial thought is that my collection query was requesting documents that would fail the security rules, but after staring at the query I don't think that's true...

As a test, I changed up my security rules to test what would pass using the help of the [debug function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.debug). I ended up realizing that the check fails every time I reference the `studyId` variable. As an example the following match statement fails.

```
match /study/{studyId}/{document=**} {
  // Deny all requests to create, update, or delete the study
  allow create, update, delete: if false

  // Allow the requestor to read the study if it is published
  allow read: if debug(debug(true) && (debug(studyId) != null));
}
```

When looking at the `firestore-debug.log`, if I run the query that requests a single document I see the following logged:

```
bool_value: true

string_value: "rMxuVTJ0O15qPjMbpEU1"

bool_value: true
```

however, when running the collection query the following is logged:

```
bool_value: true
```

I've never run into the document id wildcard throwing an error like this. I can't determine if this is an error with my match statement or my query, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your use-case really is but you don't have to use `get()` when trying to read data from the document being accessed or read. You should use **[`resource.data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation)** instead. See Firestore Rule below:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function isStudyPublished() {
      return resource.data.status == "published";
    }

    // Match for participant permissioning
    match /study/{studyId}/{document=**} {

      // Deny all requests to create, update, or delete the study
      allow create, update, delete: if false

      // Allow the requestor to read the study if it is published
      allow read: if isStudyPublished();
    }
  }
}
```

---

UPDATE:

When accessing your subcollection, your query should be matched with your security rules. You should have the document ID of the root collection to access your subcollection. E.g:

```
// Document-ID refers to study's document
let q = query(collection(db, "study", <DOCUMENT-ID>, <SUBCOLLECTION-NAME>), where(<FIELDNAME>, "==", <STRING>));
```

Security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /study/{studyId} {
      // Deny all requests to create, update, or delete the study
      allow create, update, delete: if false

      // Do all restrictions here for the study collection.

      function isStudyPublished() {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/study/$(studyId)).data.status == "published";
      }

      // Rules for accessing subcollection of study collection.
      match /subcollection-name/{docId} {
        // Allow read if the document referenced from the study collection is published.
        allow read: if isStudyPublished();

        // Do all restrictions here for study's subcollection.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The sample rule above will only allow reads to the subcollection documents if the referenced document from the `study` collection is tagged as published.

Comment: That is true when I am accessing the base study document at ``/study/{studyId}/``. However, when accessing a sub-collection with a path ``/study/{studyId}/{document=**}`` then resource.data is not the root study doc, and the check fails. The other option I see is creating two-match statements (one for the root document and one for the sub-collections), and two ``isStudyPublished()`` functions, one that used ``resource.data`` and one that used ``get``.  This would save reads, but increase the size and complexity of my rules. Do you have an opinion of the best approach?

Comment: Your query should be matched with your security rules but what I'm seeing in your question is accessing your root collection which is `study`. If you want to have security rules when accessing the subcollection, you must have created another match statement into it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Bernard, `/study/{studyId}/{document=**}` is a sub collection path and not a path to documents, you might need to change that to `/study/{studyId}` simply, to target the study documents or add go deeper to `/study/{studyId}/subCollectionNam/{document=**}` to target documents in subCollectionName. You should explicity set the exact name of the sub collection too (I suppose)

Comment: @Obumuneme I am using the recursive wildcard syntax, the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards) states that it  "matches any document in the collection as well as any document in a subcollection." Is this an error in the docs?

Comment: No not the docs. What if you used [collectionGroup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) instead as you seem to to target documents in subcollections. Secondly, I can't seem to reconcile the JS code you posted with the queries you're trying to run, that's with the COLLECTION_KEYS.STUDY because it's not clear from the snippets the exact collection or documents you're querying you see